# Downloading and building O3D

Tags: command-line, shell, svn, open-source, chromium

I'm trying to get a program called O3D into my computer by following [the instructions on O3D's wiki](https://code.google.com/p/o3d/wiki/HowToBuild).

I tried to download the project to my directory but the prompt gave me this answer:

```
gclient is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable or batch file
```

**Here's an extract from the step-by-step by Google:**

> Checking out the code
>
> The gclient config step only needs to be run once to set up your working directory. It creates a `.gclient` file in your working directory that identifies the corresponding structure to pull from the repository. The gclient sync step creates several subdirectories. To update your tree in the future, you only need to run gclient sync from anywhere within your working directory.
>
> Create a directory to hold your source code. We will call it `$O3D_ROOT` below.
>   Important: Make sure the full directory path has no spaces.
>
> In a shell window, execute the following commands:
>
> ```
> cd $O3D_ROOT
> gclient config http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/o3d
> ```
>
> To download the initial code, update your checkout as described below.
>
> ```
> cd $O3D_ROOT
> gclient sync
> ```

**ERRORS WHEN I TRY TO BUILD:**

```
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '__stdcall'  c:\$o3d_root\base\win\i18n.cc   51  base
Error   2   error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\$o3d_root\base\win\i18n.cc   51  base
Error   3   error C2065: 'GetPreferredUILanguages_Fn' : undeclared identifier   c:\$o3d_root\base\win\i18n.cc   53  base
Error   4   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'get_preferred_ui_languages'  c:\$o3d_root\base\win\i18n.cc   53  base
Error   5   error C2065: 'get_preferred_ui_languages' : undeclared identifier   c:\$o3d_root\base\win\i18n.cc   53  base
Error   6   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'GetPreferredUILanguages_Fn' c:\$o3d_root\base\win\i18n.cc   54  base
Error   7   error C2065: 'get_preferred_ui_languages' : undeclared identifier   c:\$o3d_root\base\win\i18n.cc   56  base
Error   8   error C3861: 'get_preferred_ui_languages': identifier not found c:\$o3d_root\base\win\i18n.cc   60  base
Error   9   error C3861: 'get_preferred_ui_languages': identifier not found c:\$o3d_root\base\win\i18n.cc   64  base
Error   10  error C2471: cannot update program database 'c:\$o3d_root\o3d\build\debug\obj\o3dcoreplatform\o3dcoreplatform\vc80.pdb' c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\stream_bank_d3d9.cc  1   o3dCorePlatform
Error   11  error C2471: cannot update program database 'c:\$o3d_root\o3d\build\debug\obj\o3dcoreplatform\o3dcoreplatform\vc80.pdb' c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\effect_d3d9.cc   1   o3dCorePlatform
Error   12  error C2471: cannot update program database 'c:\$o3d_root\o3d\build\debug\obj\o3dcoreplatform\o3dcoreplatform\vc80.pdb' c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\utils_d3d9.cc    1   o3dCorePlatform
Error   13  error C2065: 'PKEY_AppUserModel_ID' : undeclared identifier c:\$o3d_root\base\win\win_util.cc   116 base
Error   14  error C2471: cannot update program database 'c:\$o3d_root\o3d\build\debug\obj\o3dcoreplatform\o3dcoreplatform\vc80.pdb' c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\buffer_d3d9.cc   1   o3dCorePlatform
Error   15  fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\build\debug\lib\base.lib'  cactions    cactions
Error   16  fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation   c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\utils_d3d9.cc    120 o3dCorePlatform
Error   17  error C2471: cannot update program database 'c:\$o3d_root\o3d\build\debug\obj\o3dcoreplatform\o3dcoreplatform\vc80.pdb' c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\renderer_d3d9.cc 1   o3dCorePlatform
Error   18  fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation   c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\buffer_d3d9.cc   222 o3dCorePlatform
Error   19  error C2471: cannot update program database 'c:\$o3d_root\o3d\build\debug\obj\o3dcoreplatform\o3dcoreplatform\vc80.pdb' c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\install_check.cc 1   o3dCorePlatform
Error   20  fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation   c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\stream_bank_d3d9.cc  186 o3dCorePlatform
Error   21  error C2471: cannot update program database 'c:\$o3d_root\o3d\build\debug\obj\o3dcoreplatform\o3dcoreplatform\vc80.pdb' c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\texture_d3d9.cc  1   o3dCorePlatform
Error   22  fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation   c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\effect_d3d9.cc   1226    o3dCorePlatform
Error   23  error C2471: cannot update program database 'c:\$o3d_root\o3d\build\debug\obj\o3dcoreplatform\o3dcoreplatform\vc80.pdb' c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\param_cache_d3d9.cc  1   o3dCorePlatform
Error   24  fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation   c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\install_check.cc 259 o3dCorePlatform
Error   25  error C2471: cannot update program database 'c:\$o3d_root\o3d\build\debug\obj\o3dcoreplatform\o3dcoreplatform\vc80.pdb' c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\render_surface_d3d9.cc   1   o3dCorePlatform
Error   26  fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation   c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\renderer_d3d9.cc 1755    o3dCorePlatform
Error   27  error C2471: cannot update program database 'c:\$o3d_root\o3d\build\debug\obj\o3dcoreplatform\o3dcoreplatform\vc80.pdb' c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\primitive_d3d9.cc    1   o3dCorePlatform
Error   28  fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation   c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\texture_d3d9.cc  999 o3dCorePlatform
Error   29  error C2471: cannot update program database 'c:\$o3d_root\o3d\build\debug\obj\o3dcoreplatform\o3dcoreplatform\vc80.pdb' c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\sampler_d3d9.cc  1   o3dCorePlatform
Error   30  fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation   c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\param_cache_d3d9.cc  84  o3dCorePlatform
Error   31  fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation   c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\render_surface_d3d9.cc   154 o3dCorePlatform
Error   32  fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation   c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\primitive_d3d9.cc    232 o3dCorePlatform
Error   33  fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation   c:\$o3d_root\o3d\core\win\d3d9\sampler_d3d9.cc  203 o3dCorePlatform
Error   34  fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\build\debug\lib\o3dcoreplatform.lib'  standalone  standalone
Error   35  fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\build\debug\lib\o3dcoreplatform.lib'  o3dConverter    o3dConverter
Error   36  fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\build\debug\lib\o3dcoreplatform.lib'  npo3dautoplugin npo3dautoplugin
Error   37  fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\build\debug\lib\o3dcoreplatform.lib'  unit_tests  unit_tests
Error   38  error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "convert_background, and also convert_character, and also convert_beach_low_poly, and also convert_beachdemo, and also convert_dome1, and also convert_dome2, and also convert_dome3, and also convert_dome4, and also convert_kitty_151_idle_stand05_cff1, and also convert_part1, and also convert_part2, and also convert_part3, and also convert_seven_shapes, and also convert_seven_shapes_webgl, and also convert_stencil_frame, and also convert_teapot, and also convert_teapot_webgl, and also convert_yard, and also convert_yard_webgl, and also convert_agra_rug, and also convert_asimi_rug, and also convert_camden_chair, and also convert_elements_bookshelf, and also convert_ferrara_rug, and also convert_house_roofless, and also convert_lounge_chair, and also convert_lounge_chaise, and also convert_lounge_sofa, and also convert_lounge_storage_ottoman, and also convert_madison_dining_table, and also convert_miles_side_chair, and also convert_pullman_bar_stool, and also convert_puzzle_tv_stand, and also convert_stow_leather_ottoman, and also convert_tivoli_dining_table, and also convert_tivoli_miles_dining_set, and also convert_troy_chair, and also convert_troy_ottoman, and also convert_troy_sofa, and also convert_troy_storage_ottoman, and also convert_troy_twin_sleeper, and also convert_all_actors, and also convert_map1, and also convert_cube, and also convert_cube_webgl" convert_samples convert_samples
Error   39  error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Copying ../samples/assets/teapot/shaders/shader0.fx to C:\$o3d_root\o3d\build\Debug/samples/assets/teapot/shaders\shader0.fx"    copy_samples    copy_samples
Error   40  error LGHT0099 : The file with id 'pu.GoogleNpapiDll.dll' and name 'npo3d.dll|npo3dautoplugin.dll' could not be found with source path: 'C:/$o3d_root/o3d/build/Debug/npo3dautoplugin.dll'. c:\$o3d_root\o3d\installer\win\o3d.wxs  76  installer ((o3d)\(installer)\(win)\installer)
Error   41  fatal error LGHT0005: The system cannot find the file specified: C:/$o3d_root/o3d/build/Debug/cactions.dll  light.exe   installer ((o3d)\(installer)\(win)\installer)
Error   42  error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Linking installer from c:\$o3d_root\o3d\installer\win\o3d.wixobj"    installer   installer ((o3d)\(installer)\(win)\installer)
```

Comment: trying putting a .\ behind gclient

Comment: The way to do it is well written and doesn't say anything about that, anyway I've done and nothing happened

Comment: It doesn't look like you actually followed the very first instruction and installed depot tools.

Comment: Daniel, I've done it. cygwin, non-cygwin, visual studio....everything

Comment: Maybe the change to `Path` hasn't been applied? Run the following command in the command line: `echo %Path%` (non-Cygwin) / `echo $PATH` (Cygwin). If it doesn't contain the path to the depot tools at the end, try logging out of Windows and log back in. (If you're responding to another comment on this site, please add an `@` before the name, like `@Daniel` -- only then will the other person get notified about your response)

Comment: @daniel, I tried "echo %path%" it's written three times at the end. With "echo $path" there's nothing it's sends the same word "$path", I tried also with "echo $path$" but nothing

Comment: @juanma What exactly is *written three times at the end*? It should be the directory containing the non-Cygwin depot tools, including a file named `gclient.bat`. Also, what is the output of `echo %PATHEXT%`?

Comment: @Daniel At the end is written as it is "c:\depot_tools;c:\depot_tools;c:\depot_tools" and the output of echo %pathext% = ".com;.exe;.bat;.cmd;.vbs;.vbe;.js;.jse;.wsf;.wsh"

Comment: @Daniel Hey! You are a genious! I found the problem from something you wrote! Anyway, now I dowloaded all the tools and got the project downloaded, I don't really know yet if I can build it because in the first try I had like 19 errors from microsoft visual studio 2008 and it couldn't be done. Tomorrow I'll keep working on it and I'll keep you informed of the advances! Thanks a lot Daniel.

Comment: @juanma Great! Once you successfully got it running, please consider posting an answer to this question below with everything you did in addition to the official instructions, so others with the same problem can profit from your experience.

Comment: @Daniel, of course, I haven't finished yet, yesterday I tried to build it with no success, probablly because I haven't got installed the windows sdk and directX sdk ¿? don't know, but as soon as I got it I was thinking, if possible, to put a copy somewhere, its a pain nobody, not even google has this program on the net, let's see, tonight I'll kick my 9th day working on it!!!

Comment: @Daniel, Hi Daniel, just one simple question, I got the project downloaded and everything setted, under my point of view I have accomplished every single step from the google's page except one and it doesn't work. The step in question is that I got Visual Studio 2008 and the web page says "Visual Studio 2005/2008 Pro Trial will work" I'm confused but...it's so big the difference betwen bouth programs? I mean, Visual Studio 2008 (plane edition) is giving my 42 errors when I try to build it.

Comment: @juanma What, specifically, are the errors? Are they related to features of the Pro edition? You can add them to the question if they're too long for comments.

Comment: @Daniel, woah! I wrote the errors on the question. I don't think it's a problem of the project itself.... I doubt very much google would do such a crime!!! I don't know at the moment if its related with the features of the pro edition but it's pointing that way, don't you think?

Comment: @Daniel, confirmed, Trial Pro edition does the same. What can I do next? This is the biggest problem I had to face in my whole career. Don't know what to do Daniel, totally desperate, not even google guys can give me a answer. 10 days of hard work allready...

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to build the obsolete browser plugin? Is the current JS version not working for you?

Comment: @Oliver Explain that, The thing is that I made a program, lots of hours in that plugin and I'm not sure I can use the same code at this moment, if you have an idea of to do it quickly...just tell me, I know there's a migration to webGL but I don't know the steps &/or if I can use the same code.

Comment: @juanma: It is my understanding that the posted instructions relate to building the browser plugin for O3D. This plugin has been deprecated by Google. They are now using a solution that is entirely written in JavaScript with WebGL. They have a guide on [how to convert old projects to the new system](https://code.google.com/p/o3d/wiki/GettingStarted).

Comment: Thank you very much to everybody! I have done the convertion and now everything works fine.

Comment: You should post an answer containing the solution using the **Answer your Question** button. Thanks